# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance and Synthetic Events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, file-upload, jsx

I am trying to build a csv file uploader using react. I am getting the "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instances" error when the file is selected and I try to set the state with it. This is my code that gives that error:

```
const IFImport = (props) => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);



  const onUpload = async (e) => {
     const csvFile = e;
     console.log(csvFile)
     setFile(...file, csvFile)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ContentRow>
        <h1>
          <Link to={"/"}>
            <Button color="link">&lt;</Button>
          </Link>
          Upload Enrollment Information
          <ErrorList error={props.error} />
        </h1>
      </ContentRow>
      <ContentRow>
      <Label>Upload a CSV File for Enrollment</Label>
          <FormGroup>
            <div>
    {file !== null ? <p>{file.name}</p> : ""}
            </div>
            <div>
              <Input
                type="file"
                name="data.file"
                multiple={false}
                onChange={e => onUpload(e)}
                accept="/csv"
              />{" "}
            </div>
          </FormGroup>
      </ContentRow>
    </>
  );
};

export default IFImport;
```

I assumed this was an issue with setting the state here in this onUpload function so I tried no setting the state here but then I just get a synthetic even error. Can anyone tell me the best way to handle this sort of upload?

Comment: `...file` is where the error is from I think.
The fact that you initialize it with `null` might be the cause. `null` is not spreadable
Initialize it with `{}` (or `[]`, depending on how your `file` looks like)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Initializing file with `[ ]` gives me the synthetic event issue I mentioned above. So instead of console.log returning the file I selected it returns a synthetic even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are trying to spread `null` value which will obviously fail (that's the initial value for `file` in state).

Secondly - `e` isn't the file you are looking for, it's the Event object. If you want to get the uploaded files, use

```
const csvFile = e.target.files;
```

instead, which will hold every file uploaded by user as an array.